# Unable to deploy on Chalice with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deployment, aws-lambda, chalice

I'm trying to deploy AWS function with Chalice framework which uses tensorflow but it gives me following error 
'TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'

code is very simple:

```
from chalice import Chalice
import tensorflow as tf

app = Chalice(app_name='demotensor')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
    sess = tf.Session()
    print(sess.run(hello))
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

It works properly on local when I run 'chalice local' command but when I try to deploy 'chalice deploy' then it gives me an error.

requirement.txt includes:

tensorflow==1.3.0

Note: I am using windows and I have installed Anaconda 5.0 with Python 3.6, tensorflow without GPU

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely due to an **older version** of html5lib that is being used by tensorflow.

Download the newest release here:
https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/releases
and then simply extract it in you `AnacondaX/lib/pkgs` folder.

### How to compare your html5lib version to the latest one?

With every new release html5lib adds another "9" to 0.99.. (up till now). so, if you want to know how far back you are in terms of release simply count the number of "9s" in your library version and the one on the official release page.

here is another way to do it with anaconda navigator:

[image]